# Routing to a specific path on the browser address send to default route in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, module, lazy-loading

Enviroment:

- Angular 17

I am using lazy loading in angular and every time I try to go to http://localhost:4200/question/edit/1 from browser address it redirects to http://localhost:4200. It works perfectly through the router link.

I also created a RouterLoggingService to see the routes on every change but with the url http://localhost:4200/question/edit/1 the router logging prints and redirects to default.

```
RouterLogging change: / -> /user/login
```

Any idea what to do to fix this?

**router-logging.service**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RouterLoggingService {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log('RouterLoggingService loaded');
    
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        const url = event.url
        console.log("RouterLogging change:", event.url , event.urlAfterRedirects);
      });
  }
  
}
```

**app-routes.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "user/login", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "question",
    loadChildren: () => import("./question/question.module").then((m)=> m.QuestionModule)
  },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "user/login" },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutesModule {}
```

**question-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'list', component: QuestionListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: QuestionDetailComponent, resolve: { Question: questionLoadResolveFn } },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: QuestionEditComponent, resolve: { Question: questionLoadResolveFn } },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class QuestionRoutingModule { }
```

**question-load-resolver.service.ts**

```
export const questionLoadResolveFn: ResolveFn<Question> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
): Question | Observable<Question> | Promise<Question> => {
  const service = inject(QuestionService);
   

  const id = parseInt(route.paramMap.get("id"), 10);
  console.log('QuestionLoadResolver: ' + id);
  return service.findById(id);
};
```

Comment: the route `path: 'edit/:id',` should be declared **before** the route `path: ':id',`

Answer (score 0):

For standalone you need to import the base routes in a different way, we need to provide the routes array to the `provideRouter` function in the providers array of `bootstrapApplication`, Below is a working example highlighting the setup of root level routes!

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Routes,
  provideRouter,
  RouterLink,
  RouterOutlet,
} from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'user/login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'question',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./question/question.module').then((m) => m.QuestionModule),
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'user/login' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  template: `
  <a routerLink="question/edit/1">question edit</a> | 
  <a routerLink="question/list">question list</a> | 
  <a routerLink="question/1">question detail</a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
});
```

question-routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { QuestionDetailComponent } from './question-detail/question-detail.component';
import { QuestionEditComponent } from './question-edit/question-edit.component';
import { QuestionListComponent } from './question-list/question-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'list', component: QuestionListComponent },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: QuestionDetailComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    component: QuestionEditComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class QuestionRoutingModule {}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r3yyk6?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fquestion%2Fquestion-routing.ts,src%2Fquestion%2Fquestion-list%2Fquestion-list.component.ts,src%2Fquestion%2Fquestion-detail%2Fquestion-detail.component.ts,src%2Fquestion%2Fquestion-edit%2Fquestion-edit.component.ts,src%2Fquestion%2Fquestion.module.ts,src%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)